# Need hand with this avatar command, i cant mention avatar user (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I can't mention the `user.displayAvatarURL()`, and this is the code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]}); 
client.on("messageCreate", message => { 
    if(message.content === "avatar") { 
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author; 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
            .setAuthor(`${user.tag}\'s Avatar`, user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})) 
            .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512})) 
            .setFooter(`Requested by ${user.tag}`, user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})) 
            .setTimestamp() 
            .setColor("#272727") 
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed] }) 
    } 
}); 
client.login(process.env.token);
```

Where am I getting an error

Answer (score 0):

When you use `message.mentions.users.first()`, it returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), but what you are expecting it to return is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). So to fix your issue, you have to change the way you fetch the member. You also need to update the way you are setting the author and the footer in the embed details:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "avatar") {
        let user = message.mentions.members.first()
        let embed = Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor({
              name: `${user.user.tag}`,
              iconURL: user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
            })
            .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setFooter({
              text: `Requested by ${user.user.tag}`,
              iconURL: user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("#272727");
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
});
client.login(process.env.token);
```